# Removing user from role and checking

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-identity, asp.net-roles

I have two roles (freeUser , subscribedUser) and when i try to remove a user from role (subscribed user) using

```
 await UserManager.RemoveFromRoleAsync(subscription.UserId, RoleName.SubscribedUser);
```

it succesfully delete him from AspNetUserRoles table but when i check again to see if the user is subscribed using

```
     var roles = ((ClaimsIdentity)User.Identity).Claims
            .Where(c => c.Type == ClaimTypes.Role)
            .Select(c => c.Value);

        var enumerable = roles as IList<string> ?? roles.ToList();
```

or using `User.IsInRole(RoleName.SubscribedUser)`

it's return ture ! and the user is still in role subscribedUser even that i checked the AspNetUserRoles table and he is delete

Comment: Delete your cookies history, check in different browser or re-start the application. Sometimes, session will validate the user even nolonger exists in database.

Comment: Closing and start did nothing , but after i cleaned the project it worked .... so is this gonna cause a problem in production environment ? like when user subscription is ended .

Comment: And also add the comment as an answer so i can accept it .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delete your cookies history, check in different browser or re-start the application. Sometimes, session will validate the user even nolonger exists in database.

Comment: Not really, it wont cause problem in prod environment but I am not sure how you have implemented your session and log-in mechanism.. as soon as you remove the user from subscribed table then clear the session and or redirect to login page again.

Comment: I'm using a token based authentication for Xamarin mobile app ... but there are some features in the app are for subscribed users so i need to check when user try to access .

Comment: And when the subscription time end the user should be removed from subscribed user role .

Comment: Then it's simple, as soon as you remove the user from subscribtion plan then refresh the token ( I assume bearer token based on grant-type password and having short span of expiration) then those features ( accessed via server api controller) won't be authorized for that user. Does it make sense to you?

Comment: How exactly should i refresh the token ? ... the token is stored in user phone and have a span of 24 hours ... and when this span end or the user logout it will be deleted and user will be redirected to login page (but  the server will still consider it valid it's just been deleted form user phone) ... but how do i refresh it or (invalidate it when it's still valid (24 hours) ?! .

Comment: There is token revokation mechanism that can be implemented in server when user is removed from subscription plan then revoke his token at the same time then when user (having valid token stored in his mobile app) will be invalidate in server as that user is revoked. I am not infront of computer atm otherwise I would give some sample code.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186007/discussion-between-khalid-hex-and-ip-kaal).